# Удалить и Установить элемент в JSON по Пути(Массиву)

Tags: javascript, json

В общем нужно написать 3 функции для json(как для массива, так и для объекта) - `get`, `set` и `delete` которые будут работать не просто с ключом, а с массивом ключей которые идут друг за другом (путём)

`get` я смог сделать самостоятельно:

```
const get_json = (PATH, JSON_STRING) => { //PATH - МАССИВ, JSON_STRING - СТРОКА
  JSON_STRING = JSON.parse(JSON_STRING);
  PATH.forEach(prop => JSON_STRING = JSON_STRING[prop]);
  return JSON_STRING;
};
```

Но вот остальные у меня сделать не получилось(

Можете пожалуйста помочь с этим

Comment: А в чем возникли сложности? Покажите, что делали и что не получилось?

Comment: Запустил ваш пример у себя - он не работает

Comment: @SwaD Извиняюсь, перенёс с небольшой ошибкой. Теперь всё как надо

Comment: @SwaD У меня не сохранился неудачный код, но если вкратце я пытался определить последний элемент PATH и сделать изменение в исходном json только по нему, при этом проходя предыдущие элементы. Скорее всего так и надо, но я где-то допустил ошибку. Сейчас точно не скажешь где...

Comment: Какие данные подаются на вход, какие данные ожидаются на выходе по всем функциям? Так что нужны данные. У меня ваша функция ничего не делает и возвращает преобразованный из строки объект

Comment: @SwaD странно у меня сейчас функция работает. https://skr.sh/sInD0D8FEoV

Comment: Запустите вот так: `console.log(get_json([1,2], '[123, 3434, 8789]'))` и посмотрите результат )

Comment: @SwaD Это не будет иметь смысла. Код будет искать внутри 3434 элемент под номером 2. Это бы работало если бы массив выглядел как [123, [1,2,3], 8789], тогда он выведет 3

Comment: Тогда ваша задача становится еще более непонятной. Зачем передавать массив ключей и проходить по нему циклом, если надо вернуть 1 единственное первое значение из массива?

Comment: @SwaD Я немного не понял что вы имеете в виду под "первое значение из массива". Функция возвращает значение из пути, который можно очень гибко настроить, и возвращать к примеру элемент 8 в элементе 6 в элементе 9 и так до бесконечности. Но в любом случае, я похоже получил нужный мне ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как может выглядеть функция set_json, которая будет устанавливать новое значение для ключ

```
const set_json = (PATH, JSON_STRING, NEW_VALUE) => { //PATH - МАССИВ, JSON_STRING - СТРОКА, NEW_VALUE - ЛЮБОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ
  let json = JSON.parse(JSON_STRING);
  let currentProp = json;
  PATH.forEach((prop, index) => {
    if (index === PATH.length - 1) {
      currentProp[prop] = NEW_VALUE;
    } else {
      currentProp = currentProp[prop];
    }
  });
  return JSON.stringify(json);
};
```

А вот функция delete_json, которая будет удалять ключ, заданный массивом ключей

```
const delete_json = (PATH, JSON_STRING) => { //PATH - МАССИВ, JSON_STRING - СТРОКА
  let json = JSON.parse(JSON_STRING);
  let currentProp = json;
  PATH.forEach((prop, index) => {
    if (index === PATH.length - 1) {
      delete currentProp[prop];
    } else {
      currentProp = currentProp[prop];
    }
  });
  return JSON.stringify(json);
};
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Я смогу полностью протестировать это только завтра, но судя по всему это работает)